# Group a collection by n conditions

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, what would be a neat (preferably functional) way of grouping elements having `n` grouping conditions?

For example:

`class Item(val level : Int)`

Given the list: `(Item(1), Item(2), Item(5))`

and two grouping conditions:

1. `level > 0 && level < 3`
2. `level > 4`

The following lists are expected:

1. `listOf(Item(1), Item(2))`
2. `listOf(Item(5))`

The `groupBy` function takes only 1 condition argument. Is there any other function that would be helpful?

Answer (score 6):

You could return an `Int` in the lambda passed to `groupBy` which identifies your criteria. This would work for any number of conditions.

```
val l = listOf(Item(1), Item(2), Item(5))

val g = l.groupBy {
    when {
        it.level > 0 && it.level < 3 -> 0
        it.level > 4 -> 1
        // ...
        else -> null
    }
}.filterKeys { it != null }) // optional: filter out null as default key
```

Result:

> {0=[Item(level=1), Item(level=2)], 1=[Item(level=5)]}

Answer (score 0):

Try to [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) out all elements which aren't necessary and then either [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) or [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) them, e.g.:

using [`partition`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) (i.e. you only need 2 lists out of 1):

```
listSequence()
  .filter { it.level > 0 && it.level != 3 } // it seems you are only interested in levels > 0 && != 3
  .partition { it.level in 1..2 } // partition into items having 0 < level < 3 and the rest
  .run(::println) // prints: [[Item(level=1), Item(level=2)], [Item(level=5)]] (which is a pair of lists)
```

using [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) similar to what Willi Mentzel has shown:

```
listSequence()
    .filter { it.level > 0 && it.level != 3 } // if you need to filter... otherwise skip that and assign just a random group
    .groupBy { 
       when (it.level) {
         in 1..2 -> 0
         else -> 1
       }
    }
    .values.run(::println) // which also prints ([Item(level=1), Item(level=2)], [Item(level=5)]) but now is a collection of lists
```

In both cases I used a sequence as follows:

```
fun listSequence() = sequenceOf(Item(1), Item(2), Item(5), Item(-4), Item(0))
```

Depends what you want to accomplish in the end... You may also be interested in some of the other available [collection functions](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html#functions).

Comment: I think you're missing level=3 there; it should be filtered as well

Answer (score 0):

I'd also utilize `partion`, as already suggested, here. You could also chain them:

```
val cond1: (Item) -> Boolean = { it.level in 0..2 }
val cond2: (Item) -> Boolean = { it.level > 4 }
val parts = elements
    .partition { cond1(it) || cond2(it) }
    .first.partition { cond1(it) }
println(parts)
```

This will result into iterations of your input which is slightly less efficient than the `groupBy`. Still a linear runtime complexity.